# Logs are not getting exported at log sink as per the inclusion filter of timestamp

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-stackdriver

I wanted to export the logs of my AppEngine service to the cloud storage bucket. Hence, I created the log sink & I gave the destination of my cloud storage bucket.The problem is that logs are not getting exported as per my inclusion filter condition.
Inclusion Filter:-

```
resource.type="gae_app"
resource.labels.module_id="cbd-iris-app"
timestamp>="2021-07-17T01:20:00Z" AND timestamp<="2021-07-17T16:30:00Z"
```

As per the filter, I am expecting the logs to be between the timestamps mentioned in code. But, instead the logs which are getting stored are of current date & time. What exactly is wrong here ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: This is the expected behavior for GCP's [Log routing](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export)

Based on [How sinks work](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export#overview) section, looks like you can only apply to new logs and not to logs that had been already processed:

> Caution: Since routing happens for new log entries only, you can't
> route log entries that Logging received before your sink was created.

So although you set a `timestamp` filter, the sink can only take logs that are created after the sink was created.